# Android exit application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, exit

it's not recommended to exit application directly, so the point is to finish all activities so everything goes to the background and user returns to the home screen. My problem is that I have main activity, which is always launched with flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and it launches another activity, where I want to place the exit button. In order to get everything to the background I have to finish both current and main activity. I though that launching main activity with those flags and extra info that it should exit would do the trick, but the extras delivered with the intent do not reach main activity - it still gets the intent that was used by android to launch the application.

In other words, I tried something like:

```
// Exit's onClick:
Intent intent = new Intent(someContext, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("exit", true);
context.startActivity(intent);
currentActivity.finish();

// MainActivity onCreate:
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null)
{
  // application never reach this point
  boolean exit = extras.getBoolean("exit");
  if (exit)
  {
    finish();
    return;
  }
}
```

The extras are delivered. How can I get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting this 2 flags MainActivity will not reach onCreate() if it is still in the stack. This would call onNewIntent().

Check this 2 links for more information:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Exit(0);
```

//You can use that to exit the entire application, not just one activity

Answer (score 0):

Set Launch Mode of `MainActivity` as `"SingleTop"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file as follows:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, and what is more it causes even more problems with restoring activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but work to me:

On Event Listener:

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid(); 
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

call moveTaskToBack(true) on your Activity

Answer (score 0):

Simple, make a class and put a static variable and function like this:

```
public static boolean isExit = false;

public static boolean CheckExit() {
 return isExit;
}

public static void setisExit(boolean b)
{
isExit = b;
}
```

And in your Main Activity put `YourClassName.setisExit(false);` is will make sure `isExit` value is false when application start again.

To Exit:

Put this in your `OnClick` method:

```
YourClassName.setisExit(true);
finish();
```

And put this in first line of `OnResume` method of every activity:

```
if(YourClassName.CheckExit()) {
    finish();
     return super.onResume();
   }
```

By doing this every time a Activity resume is check the `isExit` value and if true then exit.

You can check my app `E Player` on google play. I implemented this method and its working fine

Comment: Static variables are lost when Android decides to recreate GUI from scratch when restoring your application. Your solution is unreliable.

Comment: Ok, but once user click exit button, now user is out of the application so if app recreate or not does it matter. Not a single time i or my E Player users feel error in exit functionality. And the class holding these static variables is a separate class not activity