# Close all activities and come to mobile's home screen

Tags: android, android-intent

When I press the log out button and come to start(main) screen and when I press the back button from main screen it comes to 2nd screen. but, i want to close the application on click of back button from main screen and close all the activities before that.
while doing research I found,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);  
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
finish();
```

but its not satisfying my requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524904/logout-functionality-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this **code** that I referred from here [How to exit from the application and show the home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226495/android-exit-application-code):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Although Android's design does not favor exiting an application by choice.

**Related Links:**

[How to close Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092951/how-to-close-android-application)

[Android exit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255509/android-exit-application?rq=1)

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOPFLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK worked for me

Comment: @RachitaNanda: Hi, i have another doubt.. your above code is satisfying my requirement. but when i press mobile's back button (not my app's back button) it comes to 2nd screen.. it should close the app. and one more thing that is when i press back button from the app(i did the above code on back button) and when i start the app again its not displaying splash screen.. but directly giving login screen.?? tell me the solution.

Comment: mobile's back button finishes the current activity and takes you to previous activity on stack .If you want same behavior on hard key back press ,just override  onbackpressed() or onkeydown() of  activity and add your code there.I can't say anything about the other problem without the code ,you can ask another question on SO as its a different prob

Answer (score 0):

just add  line in your code and this will work fine

```
   startActivity(intent);
```